# jQuery fire function when previous <select> is enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three `<select>` elements.

- Select 1
- Select 2
- Select 3

Select 1 is enabled, while Select 2 & 3 are disabled by default, as they depend on their "previousSibling".

Select 1 is populated with options coming from a MySQL query. When one of this options is selected, the following code enables Select 2 and populates it with an AJAX call:

```
$("#select1").change(function(){
       var id = $(this).val();
       var dataString = 'id='+ id;
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: './php/selectProperty.php?nocache=' +
             (new Date()).getTime(),
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           async: false,
           success: function(html){
                 $("#select2").html(html);
                 $('#select2').prop("disabled", false);// Element(s) are now enabled.
           }});
});
```

Although Select3 follows the same methodology (`$("#select2").change(function()...`) it is not being enabled or populated, as I can imagine that the change method expects an explicit change from the user's side and not just a change in the DOM. Because sometimes Select 2 has only one option, change() will never fire.

Is there an alternative method for firing the population of Select 3 and enable it? For example, when Select 2 lose its disabled property?

Comment: Hopely you have your ajax at the bottom of your page inside a document reday.  Also I would change this: $("#select1").change(function() to this $("#select1").on(''change",function()

Comment: did you try adding the change event handler for select2 right after you added the html results ?

Comment: @franco ajax is at the end of the document inside a document ready, but you are right. The .on did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st:** you need to use .on()

```
$("#select2").on('change',function(){});
```

or

```
$("body").on('change', '#select2' ,function(){});
```

but I think the .on() will work

**2nd:** to make just one code for all of them

```
$('select[id^="select"]').on('change',function(){
  var ThisIt = $(this);
  var id= ThisIt.val();
  var getNextSelect = ThisIt.next('select[id^="select"]');
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: './php/selectProperty.php?nocache=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success: function(html){
      getNextSelect.html(html).promise().done(function(){
            getNextSelect.prop("disabled", false); // Element(s) are now enabled.
      });
    } 
  });
});
```

Comment: It's already the nth time that I have the same error with DOM modification and its binding to the document. I don't know if I'm going to learn it someday. Your solution does not only works. The 2nd option is delicious and my code seems a lot better now.

Comment: @agustin jquery you're totally welcome .. Very Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

First, we'll need to update the HTML so that it isn't reliant on hard coded id's, which makes it easier for us to maintain in the future.

Second, we can specify a parent element to attach our event handler; instead of attaching it directly to each select menu. In this case I'm using the class ".chain-select" as my parent element.

```
<div class="chain-select">

    <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>4</option>
    </select>

    <select disabled></select>

    <select disabled></select>

    <select disabled></select>

    <select disabled></select>

</div>
```

JavaScript

Now that we've attached our event handler to the ".chain-select" it will be used as our delegated target. This means that if user changes any select menu, which is a descendant of our ".chain-select" it will trigger our event handler after the event has bubbled up to the delegated target.

This approach is perfect if you are working with multiple elements you want to add some event based functionality to or element that are loaded in via Ajax.

```
<script>

    // Document Ready
    $(function () {


         $('.chain-select').on('change', 'select', function (e) {
            var $select = $(e.currentTarget);

            // RESET ALL NOT YET SELECTED SELECT MENUS 
            $select.nextAll('select').prop('disabled', true).empty();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: './php/selectProperty.php?nocache=' + (new Date()).getTime(),
                data: {
                    id: $select.val()
                },
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                success: function (html) {

                    // ENABLE AND POPULATE THE NEXT SELECT MENU
                    $select.next('select').html(html).prop('disabled', false);

                }
            });

        });

    });

 </script>
```